# ace editor line margin

Tags: javascript, css, ace-editor

I trying to use Ace editor as custom-markdown editor for blog admin panel. I set wrap mode on and now I want to set margin-bottom of each line to emulate normal text flow, with gaps between paragraphs. The problem is, when I tried to do

```
.ace_line_group
    margin-bottom: 24px
```

margin was applied, but the carret is ignore this. When I click on first line on second paragraph, carret renders just in place where second paragraph should start if I don't set margin-bottom. So, how to deal with it? I didn't found any mentions about one-line margin in docs.

On picture: green mark is a gap. There is *no* empty new line between lines, and there should not be. Red mark is a cursor position (and "current line" highlighter) when I actually put it between words "vulputate" and "eros" of second paragraph.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could disable print margin completely by adding:
`showPrintMargin={false}`